# ¿A qué se debe el siguiente mensaje de error al intentar reemplazar una cadena en Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

***some characters cannot be mapped using cp1252 character encoding***

Estoy intentando reemplazar una cadena correspondiente al título de un esquema de BD codificado en eclipse a la que le falta un número, ***"esquema_propio por esquema1_propio"*** y cuando pulso sobre el botón para reemplazar eclipse me lanza la siguiente alerta de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He leído que se puede deber al estar usando un estilo u otro de enconding pero existe algún tipo de solución para esto? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse utiliza CP1252 por defecto como estándar de codificación para sus archivos. Esto lo puedes ver en Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, bajo la opción "Text file encoding" (el valor que yo utilizo es UTF-8 para todos mis archivos):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo más probable es que el archivo con el que estés trabajando está codificado en otro formato, posiblemente UTF-8 u otro distinto. Entonces, cuando quiere hacer la búsqueda correspondiente, es posible que algunos caracteres no se encuentren igual, suele pasar con las vocales con tilde como `á` y la letra `ñ` (mayúsculas o minúsculas).

Te recomiendo tener cuidado cuando intentes editar archivos de texto en eclipse. Verifica que usas la codificación adecuada. O quizás debas utilizar otro programa para estos cambios.

Comment: Perfecto, solucionado, lo tenía por defecto, he pulsado en otros y lo he dejado como lo tienes tú y me lo ha reemplazado a la perfección. Muchas gracias @Luiggi Mendoza! :)